# How to permanently Disable actionbar/navigationbar/statusbar android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout, system

I have a rooted device that runs a custom launcher, I need to remove the actionbar/navigationbar/statusbar so that only the launcher can be used, and non of the native android stuff can be accessed.
I've tried almost all of the method's I could find on stackoverflow.
So I really help trying to figure out why this is not working.

I've also tried using immersive UI flags, but this still lets you access the navigation changes when you change focus.

```
    @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}
private void hideSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the statusbar or navigationbar from AndroidManifest.xml. The only thing you could do is start immersive mode, but that  would only hide them. So they would be still accessible.

You can take a look at GravityBox' sources, they disable/enable the navigationbar with root.

Comment: I have not only tried it, from the manifest, I've tried over 20 different methods programmatically. `Also getActionBar.hide()` returns null in any case. and `getSupportActionBar()` does not exist.

Comment: Can you show an example of their method of disabling the bar?

Comment: getActionBar obviously returns null. You've disabled the Action Bar in your theme.

Comment: Pretty sure they use immersive mode, which still lets you access the actionbar if requested.

Comment: First: Actionbar != Navigationbar

Comment: Second: No, they have a feature to disable the navigationbar completly, using xposed i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use themes that have no action bar and use fullscreen.

eg `android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`

In your `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme"
       parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"/>

    <style name="AppTheme"
       parent="AppBaseTheme">
     // to do...
```

Have a look here:

[Using Platform Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles)

You can also set you app to be the home launcher for the device.

In terms of preventing people access to the settings, 4.2.2 is not helpful, and this is difficult outside of lollipop, where user accounts can be created with restricted access. As the user can always pull down to get the settings.
There are apps you can use that prevent users from uninstalling apps and making changes to settings. These are password protected, and can work well with other restrictive measures.